# How to define attributes?

Tags: java, attributes

The below question is confusing me, I am not sure if my thinking is right. This is the question

> Given three straight lines a, b & c. They will be able to form a
>   triangle provided that sum of any two lines is always greater than the
>   third line (i.e. a + b > c and b + c > a and a + c
>
> > b). Write a Java class Triangle with the following:

```
Attributes: length of the three sides of the triangle 
Behaviour:
```

> - Constructor that sets the length of the three sides to the values passed in. The constructor should throw an InvalidValueException
>     object when the values are not able to form a triangle.
>
>   - findArea() method to calculate the area of the Triangle object using the formula area = a +b+c

Just a heads up the next part of the question is to create a GUI. I already did that.

So the above question is it asking me to just simply get the values, but from where? Is it through the GUI? or Commandline base? the question was not specific so can I assume that simmply create variables that are ready to accept the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just hardcode it for the moment in a test class or similar e.g.

```
new Triangle(3,4,5);
```

In this scenario you're interested in testing your code for various functions (valid vs. invalid) and so I would write a test (or multiple tests) that have particular sets of data e.g.

```
   // expected to be ok
   new Triangle(3,4,5);

   // expected exception
   new Triangle(1,1,3);
```

In the latter case you'd want to catch the exception and bail out of your program with an error *if you don't get an exception*.

You might want to check out [unit test frameworks](http://www.junit.org) to help you with this.

Edit: Your amended question now contains setters for the `Triangle` sides. I think you're better off making the fields read only, doing this on construction and throwing an Exception from the constructor. If you need setters, then you have to call the `validate()` method at some stage otherwise you're potentially creating a `Triangle` which is invalid. Note that you can't call the validator upon each setter invocation since you may be setting multiple sides and an intermediate state may be invalid.

Comment: Hey man I have updated my original post is this is what my question is asking?

Comment: I've amended my answer. I think you should bin your setters and make your Triangle immutable

Answer (score 1):

Well if you were asked to develop a GUI I really think the values must be entered throught it... and the Triangle class must have 3 properties: a, b and c.

Comment: Well the GUI part is later on this is only for the part b of the question, so no relation to the GUI, the question is mainly testing on the error handling.

Answer (score 0):

> So the above question is it asking me to just simply get the values, but from where?

From the constructor arguments. That is what the following means:

> *"Constructor that sets the length of the three sides to the values passed in."*

For instance:

```
    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c;
    }
```

---

> Is it through the GUI? or Commandline base?

The GUI (or command line entry point) would presumably get values from somewhere and pass them as constructor arguments.  Or ... *any* code could simply instantiate a `Triangle` with hard-wired values for the sides; e.g.

```
    Triangle pythagorasFavourite = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
```

---

> the question was not specific so can I assume that simply create variables that are ready to accept the values?

Actually, it was specific: see above.

---

Note however that the area of a triangle is NOT `area = a + b + c`.  The real formula is:

> Area of Triangle when the length of the three sides is known is
>
> ```
>  1/4 * square-root [ P * (P-2a) * (P-2b) * (P-2c)]
> ```
>
> where `P` is total perimeter
>   and `a`, `b` and `c` are the lengths of the three sides.

Reference: http://library.thinkquest.org/20991/gather/formula/data/297.html

Comment: yes stepehen that is what I was asked but just mentioned it for easy understanding just like foo+bar = foobar

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: I was just talking about your last comment on area of triangle, letting you know that I do know the formula but I just editied the formula for easy understanding

Comment: @noobprogrammer - but in fact, your edit had the opposite effect.